# Rails and user defined actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple scenario that is proving difficult for some strange reason - I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake.

I have a GuestsController that I need to define my own actions and routes for. It only has one action at the moment because I can't get round this weird problem. Here is the action:

```
def booking
  @booking = Booking.where(:friendly_id => params[:friendly_id])
end
```

The route that produces the param value is:

```
match '/:friendly_id', to: 'guests#booking',     via: 'get'
```

and this is close to the end of my routes.rb

so in my view booking.html.rb I want to show the id of the booking relating to the friendly_id given

```
<%= @booking.id %>
```

and i get an error: **NoMethodError in Guests#booking**

Anyone got an idea why this is happening as it's giving me a headache.

Comment: can you post the url path you have written

Comment: try to find out the route path using rake routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't retrieve a Booking, you generate an ActiveRecord::Relation :

```
@booking = Booking.where(:friendly_id => params[:friendly_id])
# should be
@booking = Booking.where(:friendly_id => params[:friendly_id]).first
# or
@booking = Booking.find_by(:friendly_id => params[:friendly_id])
```

Comment: of course - I need to be finding one booking specifically don't I! arghh thanks